# How to extract/display last two days of a time series?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to run a `R-Script`which only displays the last couple of days of my time series, for example last two days instead of the complete series:

Data:

```
dates <- as.POSIXct(seq(as.Date("2015-08-01"), as.Date("2015-08-31"), by = "days"))

b<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,4,5,6,8,1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,2,1,5)
c<-c(9,8,7,6,5,4,5,6,7,3,2,2,3,4,5,6,7,7,3,4,6,7,3,4,2,6,7,8,9,1,1)
d<-c(1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,4,4,1,6,7,8,4,3,2,8,8)
e<-seq(1,31,1)
df<-data.frame(dates,b,c,d,e)


new <- melt(df , id.vars = 'dates', variable.name = 'series')


ggplot(new,aes(x=dates,y=value,colour=variable,group=variable)) + 
geom_line() + 
scale_x_datetime() + 
xlab("Date") + 
ylab("Scale")
```

I tried to define ranges here `scale_x_datetime()`but nothing seems to work.

[image]

Comment: do you mean you only want the axis to show the last two days, or the graph to only have two days?

Comment: Have you thought of using a `subset`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to use a `subset`:

EDIT: replaced manual selection of the date to an automatic last 3 days

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

dates <- as.POSIXct(seq(as.Date("2015-08-01"), as.Date("2015-08-31"), by = "days"))

b<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,4,5,6,8,1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,2,1,5)
c<-c(9,8,7,6,5,4,5,6,7,3,2,2,3,4,5,6,7,7,3,4,6,7,3,4,2,6,7,8,9,1,1)
d<-c(1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,4,4,1,6,7,8,4,3,2,8,8)
e<-seq(1,31,1)
df<-data.frame(dates,b,c,d,e)


new <- melt(df , id.vars = 'dates', variable.name = 'series')
nrdays <- 3

ggplot(subset(new, new$dates >= as.POSIXct(max(new$dates)-(nrdays*60*60*24))), #POSIXct uses seconds, hence the *60sec*60min*24hours
       aes(x=dates,y=value,colour=series,group=series)) + 
       geom_line() + 
       scale_x_datetime() + 
       xlab("Date") + 
       ylab("Scale")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. My problem is, that I dont want to manuelly define the time range as in your example `new$dates >= as.POSIXct("2015-09-11")` aka last two days. I would like to define it just once for a whole year for example.

Comment: @Googme I don't understand what you mean by once for a whole year, but i've updated my answer, so it automatically selects the last three days (nr days customizable). Is that better?

Comment: Yes thanks. May I ask you to explain `as.POSIXct(max(new$dates)-(nrdays*60*60*24)`

Comment: @Googme Sure. POSIXct objects use seconds as a base. So subtracting 3*60sec*60min*24hours results in subtracting 3 days, from the maximum in your dataset. The as.POSIXct might be redundant, i'm not sure about that.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to only "shorten" the graph to show the last two days, you could use `slice` and a `group_by` (from `dplyr`, to keep with the same motif), like so:

```
library(dplyr)
new %>% group_by(series) %>% slice(9:10) %>% ggplot(aes(x=dates,y=value,colour=series,group=series)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  scale_x_datetime() + 
  xlab("Date") + 
  ylab("Scale")
```

This should yield the following graph:

[image]

Note that what you are doing with the first three commands (before your plot call) is getting the last two observations per group of your data.frame:

```
new %>% group_by(series) %>% slice(9:10)
#Source: local data frame [8 x 3]
#Groups: series [4]
#
#                dates series value
#               (time) (fctr) (dbl)
#1 2015-09-12 02:00:00      b     9
#2 2015-09-13 02:00:00      b     1
#3 2015-09-12 02:00:00      c     1
#4 2015-09-13 02:00:00      c    10
#5 2015-09-12 02:00:00      d     0
#6 2015-09-13 02:00:00      d     0
#7 2015-09-12 02:00:00      e    10
#8 2015-09-13 02:00:00      e    11
```

Comment: Hi, thx for the `slice` command. Using my example and your suggestion `new %>% group_by(series) %>% slice(9:10)` results in: `Error: unknown column 'series`

Comment: I changed the values from your example. Switch it to 'your original values' (otherwise it didn't work in your reproducible code)

Comment: @Googme you should switch to your original values: `aes(x=dates,y=value,colour=variable,group=variable)`

Comment: Ah ok. `new %>% group_by(variable) %>% slice(9:10)` that works thx. However, the complete line gives error on my original data: `Error in prettyDate(x = x, n = n, min.n = min.n, sep = sep, ...) : 
  range too small for 'min.n`

Comment: Is your actual data too long? could you edit your post to show it? Edit: Note that I had to switch your original example from (`e`) 14 to 11 as it didn't match the length of your other columns

Comment: Yes my data  would consist of `30-700 obs`.  Because of that I would like to display only the last couple of days.

Comment: There is something wrong, because the graph in your answer differs greatly from the last few days of the graph in the question by @Googme